# Exception during sklearn prediction: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict' (Error code: 2)

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to follow this tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/deploying-models).

Here, I am trying to predict the output of a simple model(Titanic) for an input_json in my local directory.

I am stuck at the part of making a local prediction, where I need to give an input.json.

For the input json I provided, I am repeatedly getting an error as Exception during sklearn prediction: float() argument must be a string or
a number, not 'dict' (Error code: 2)

My input.json file contains:

`{"Pclass" : 3, "SibSp" : 1, "Parch" : 0, "Sex_female" : 0, "Sex_male" : 1}`

Also, I have removed all the float features from the input of the trained model, and above features are the only features used for the same.

Comment: provide some code and errors if any

Answer (score 0):

Sklearn doesn't work with `json`. You need to convert your data into something like a numpy array or a pandas dataframe. In this case a pandas dataframe is probably more convenient. It would look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# the following line is just to simulate
# pass just your dicts to from_records below
data= [
    {"Pclass" : 3, "SibSp" : 1, "Parch" : 0, "Sex_female" : 0, "Sex_male" : 1},
    {"Pclass" : 3, "SibSp" : 2, "Parch" : 0, "Sex_female" : 1, "Sex_male" : 0},
]

df= pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

Then pass this dataframe `df` to train your model. Don't forget to pass your labels as well. If they are for example part of the json documents above (e.g. key=survived), you can train your model like this:

```
your_model.fit(df[['PClass', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Sex_female', 'Sex_male']], df['survived'])
```